# Laravel 5.4 Authentication empty $request

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I'm using the AdminLte2 Laravel Package found here. [Laravel AdminLTE2](https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel)

This package uses Vue.js on the login form to redirect the user if he/she is authenticated successfully or simply re-loads the login form.

I have my project installed locally on my VM using Homestead. The login functionality here works 100%

However, on my staging server (http://sugarcoated.co/demo/vcc-backoffice/public/login), I am unable login. I have done some digging through the code which has yielded the following results.

I have the **RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Log;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        Log::debug($request);
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

When I log the $request that is coming through on my **VM** I get the correct post variables which include the email and password.

```
[2017-11-07 11:25:17] local.DEBUG: array (
  'email' => 'christiansen.marcus@gmail.com',
  'password' => 'wer',
  'remember' => NULL,
)
```

When I log the results on my staging site I get an empty request.

```
[2017-11-07 11:26:38] production.DEBUG: array (
)
```

I'm not sure if this is because perhaps the site isn't https, but for some reason, the post request is not being sent through to the Middleware.

Is there anything I could have missed when deploying the app?

**DEPLOYMENT PROCESS**

I'm deploying to a staging server using Beanstalk. Once all files are deployed I,

1. composer install (/vendor)
2. npm install (/node_modules)
3. add the .env file and update DB connection details 
   3.1 DB connection details are correct as I'm successfully able to run **php artisan migrate --seed**
4. Change environment to 'production'

**UPDATE**

The LoginForm.vue file is responsible for submitting the form.
The method is:

```
submit () {
      this.form.post('/public/login')
       .then(response => {
         var component = this;
         setTimeout(function(){
           component.redirect(response)
         }, 2500);
       })
       .catch(error => {
         console.log(this.trans('adminlte_lang_message.loginerror') + ':' + error)
       })
    },
```

I thought perhaps changing the post URL could do the trick (since I have to actually access the public folder), however, this doesn't work either.

Log::debug($request->fullUrl()); => http://sugarcoated.co/demo/vcc-backoffice/public/login

**UPDATE**
When I console.log(this.form) in LoginForm.vue The object is empty on the staging server but fine on my local machine. How can this be?

'Staging'
[image]

'Local'
[image]

Comment: How is your deploying workflow? Your server configuration might be interfering with Laravel .htaccess

Comment: @Asur I've added my deployment process. I hope this helps?!

Comment: Are you using any load balancers or proxies?

Comment: Not that I know of. I'm hosting this site on Digital Ocean!

Comment: I didn't know you could log an object like `Log::debug($request);`. I'm guessing your dumps come from `Log::debug($request->all());` right?

Comment: @Asur I added the snipped from the .vue file. I thought perhaps the post URL was incorrect since the site is on a subfolder on my staging site I'm accessing the public folder in the URL. When I try to authenticate, the Middleware fires because it logs it to the console, however, neither the $request nor any methods are being logged.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158413/discussion-between-marcus-christiansen-and-asur).